# Batch convert txt file encoding

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch, shell-script

I have about 700 files that were the results of a closed caption software process. I can open the files on my PC or Mac in a GUI, but when I open it on the server with nano, I get this:

```
ï¿½ï¿½0^@0^@;^@0^@0^@;^@0^@0^@;^@0^@0^@ ^@0^@0^@;^@0^@0^@;^@0^@6^@;^@0^@0^@
^@
^@N^@o^@t^@ ^@A^@v^@a^@i^@l^@a^@b^@l^@e^@
```

Here are the results from a few of the command line things I have tried:

```
#file infile.txt 
infile.txt: data

# file -bi --mime-encoding  infile.txt 
application/octet-stream; charset=binary

recode ../CR-LF infile.txt
#file -bi --mime-encoding  infile.txt

#iconv -f binary -t uff-8 infile.txt > out.txt
iconv: conversions from `binary' and to `uff-8' are not supported

#recode ../CR-LF infile.txt
#recode UTF8..ISO-8859-15 infile.txt 
# file -bi --mime-encoding  infile.txt 
text/plain; charset=utf-16le

#xxd infile.txt | head -5
0000000: fffe 3000 3000 3b00 3000 3000 3b00 3000  ..0.0.;.0.0.;.0.
0000010: 3000 3b00 3000 3000 2000 3000 3000 3b00  0.;.0.0. .0.0.;.
0000020: 3000 3000 3b00 3000 3600 3b00 3000 3000  0.0.;.0.6.;.0.0.
0000030: 0d00 0d0a 004e 006f 0074 0020 0041 0076  .....N.o.t. .A.v
0000040: 0061 0069 006c 0061 0062 006c 0065 00    .a.i.l.a.b.l.e.
```

The actual file looks like this (it turns out it wasn't the best choice, I accidentally chose one without much of anything in it):

`00;00;00;00 00;00;06;00
Not Available`

Then if I nano the file, I get text at the bottom that says it was converted from DOS and Mac format, but it is still all garbage. I need to be able to loop through the files and import the data into a database, but of course I can't do that if the server isn't able to read the format.

I would like to find a long term solution since I will be generating lots of these in the future, and would rather not use Windows powershell or equivalent but incorporate the conversion into my process.

Comment: What GUI do you open them in? A text editor like Notepad or TextEdit, or some special application?

Comment: On Windows I used Notepad or Editplus, on my mac I used TextEdit

Comment: You were likely going the right direction with the iconv, but you passed invalid parameters.  It might be useful if you included a few lines of the original file.  Update your question with the output of something like `xxd original_file | head -5`.  BTW, I suspect you have an invalid or missing BOM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Zoredache, I updated the question and will look into the BOM possibility.

Comment: So your file does have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) [see the FFFE at 0x0).  It tells me your current file seems to be a little endian UTF-16.  Are you sure you want to downgrade change the format?  Why are you using nano to view these files?  Surely that isn't part of your batch process.  I don't think nano actually supports unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution for me ended up being to use recode. There isn't a lot of great documentation, but the trick was to use the -f option to force it to change it.

```
recode -f UTF-7 *.txt
```